# How wide does curb need to be for shower glass wall?

Tags: shower, glass

I am framing a short wall and a curb to install tile and then a glass wall divider for a walk in shower.

The shower is already cramped, so I'm trying to figure out how wide the curb needs to be to hold the glass.  I can't move any further to the left because there is a door in the way (and yes, I know I need a door stop to protect the glass).

I was thinking of making a small curb using 2x3 instead of 2x4 so the curb would be 2.5" wide plus board+tile as opposed to 3.5" wide plus board+tile, but I'm worried that won't be wide enough to properly hold the glass.  Is this a real concern, or would that work fine?

[image: shower from overhead]

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the nuances of the glass wall in question? Have you consulted its literature?

Answer (score 2):

The glass should be held along the wall of the shower. The base or curb holds the weight, but if anchored well at the wall it should not move with regular use.

2x3s are ok but it would be better if you ripped some PT 2x4s and use those.
If there is a leak they will withstand the water longer than the untreated wood.

Anchor the wood with screws if you have a wood floor.  If it's concrete use a [Polyurethane](https://www.lowes.com/pd/LOCTITE-PL-Premium-3x-Brown-Polyurethane-Interior-Exterior-Construction-Adhesive-Actual-Net-Contents-10-fl-oz/1000194201?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-1000194201-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwqZSlBhBwEiwAfoZUIAEW6xqEd5nb6Ox2w1EzRAHJAHa26zaOhtOv4W2Do64B0d8cOF3AfhoCEVoQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)construction adhesive and [Tapcons](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Tapcon-10-Pack-3-in-x-3-8-in-Concrete-Anchors/4686253?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-hdw-_-ggl-_-LIA_HDW_126_Fastening-_-4686253-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwqZSlBhBwEiwAfoZUIPeBVe-muj0RLTP-fMIeUgy2TnGzavjyE1e8prNKc4uwyuFI2eVHzBoC0LkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Anchor the glass with something like [shower glass anchors](https://www.build.com/sure-loc-shr-c2bv/s1905094?uid=4500157) 2 or 3 on the wall and 1 or 2 at the base will work Depending on the size of the glass.

Seal with clear silicone and you are golden.

Comment: I hadn't considered using PT, but that makes sense.  I'll look into that.

Comment: @daveola I'm sure you've taken the [tour] by now. The proper way to show appreciation for an answer is to click the up vote arrow.

Comment: I was hoping for a citation for 2x3s being okay - also - one other concern I have is that I've read that PT should only be used for wood that's on concrete, otherwise standard wood should be used.  Either way, voted up.

Comment: @ daveola,  I know it isn't wise to build an entire interior wall out of PT. However this is just a few feet of shower curb.  TBH, when I was faced with not enough PT to do a complete curb, I have done the base in PT and the 2 courses over it in whitewood studs. It was my own shower, so if it went south with a leak and subsequent wood rot it was my own fault.